# Responsive text over image vertically centered

Tags: css, wordpress, image, text, center

I have my text positioned in an image with the margin-top: - px in 2 columns.
See it here: http://nlbure-govobanda.savviihq.com/bureau/

I want to know how  to center it vertically on every screen? So it automatically scales to the middle of the image, no matter what device.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: That would be a good idea to share simplified version of your code, instead of providing a link, as the contents of the link target are subject to change in future

Answer (score 1):

using `relative` position property and also `top:50%`, you may do it like this:

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```